# Same domain name for website and webapplication which are hosted at two separate geo-graphical locations

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I have a website "http://www.mywebsite.com" which is hosted with a hosting solution vendor (shared hosting). I now want to put few applications which are accessible on the same domain i.e. "http://www.mywebsite.com/mywebapp". I have a mandate not to use subdomain (thus "mywebapp.mywebsite.com" is not accepted a solution)

I am aware that my website is hosted on Apache Server (shared hosting space). 
My application is hosted on a completely different machine with Apache Tomcat. I am aware of the mod_jk Apache module, to link with tomcat. But apart from mod_jk I think I would need some redirection. I tried to look at mod_rewrite, but I could not find a way where my website and webapplications can co-exist on the same domain name. Can someone help me with the right approach of re-direction?

Comment: Apache [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) should help you

Comment: Do you want to do redirection or proxying? Redirection will take a client from one site and redirect them to another, so the client will make a new request to a new URL (and in your case, a different hostname). Proxying will accept and forward the request to the true back-end server. I think you want proxying, here.